# Parse JSON Result To UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, get

I'm really new into swift & currently learning API by doing a project that shows list of games from [rawg.io](https://api.rawg.io/api/games) referring to the website's [doc](https://api.rawg.io/docs). I created `GameFeed.swift` & `GameDetail.swift` to pull name, release date, and rating from it and working fine in my console.

GameFeed.swift :

```
struct GameFeed: Codable {
    let results:[GameDetail]
}
```

GameDetail.swift :

```
struct GameDetail: Codable {
    let name:String
    let released:String
    let rating:Double
}
```

[image: Result in Console]

Now i'm trying to put the results to a simple `UIlabel` like `gameName.text`, `gameReleased.text` & `gameRating.text` from `ViewController.swift` so it will be show in `Main.Storyboard`

[image]

i did research on google about how to show it to these `UIlabel` by using `DispatchQueue.main.async` but when i'm declaring it, it receiving error :

> ***Value of type 'GameFeed' has no member 'name'***

same error messages also happened to `released` & `rating`. This is my `ViewController.Swift` :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var gameName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gameReleased: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gameRating: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Defining API Site
        let urlString = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
                guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        // Calling API
        let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!){
                (data, response, error) in
            
                    if error == nil && data != nil {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        do {
                            let gameFeed = try decoder.decode(GameFeed.self, from: data!)
                            print(gameFeed)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.gameName.text = gameFeed.name
                                self.gameReleased.text = gameFeed.released
                                self.gameRating.text = gameFeed.rating
                           }
                }
                        catch {
                            print("Error Parsing JSON")
                }
        }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

What should i do to make it possible to parse the data to labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GameFeed` contains an **Array** of `GameDetail`s. But you are trying to set a single `GameDetail` on those labels. You should first pull out a single `GameDetail` from that array, then assign it in a way you like.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let gameDetail = gameFeed.results.first // <- This will return the first one
    self.gameName.text = gameDetail?.name
    self.gameReleased.text = gameDetail?.released
    self.gameRating.text = gameDetail?.rating
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's now showing in my emulator. but should it be always using optional to show the value? and how is it possible not only show the first one? because my future plan is about going to declare it in a dynamic view table. is it still possible to use this way?

Comment: I think that is another question and you should ask another **after** searching about `UITableView` and `Array`s ;)

Comment: haha yes sorry for being out of topic. it's currently answered my question so far, and will looking forward to figure it out on how to do that in next step. Thank you Motjaba Hosseini.